# Check if element in XML exists that ends with matching string

Tags: c#, xml

I can see a way of searching for an element within XML by just going:

```
if(doc.SelectSingleNode("//mynode")==null)
```

But what I'm more interested in, is finding an element that matches the part of the name. Something like:

doc.SelectSingleNode ...that contains "table" in it.
So if I had a node called "AlinasTable", I want it to find that. Why it matters is because my node can inconsistently contain anything that comes before "table", like "JohnsTable" - in which case I'd want that to be returned. So something more generic.

Cheers.

Comment: you may perhaps need to traverse the xml tree to find the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256195(v=vs.110).aspx) function, as in the following [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx) expression:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(name(), 'Table')]")
```